# Analog Computer Symbols

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, shapes

I am trying to draw analog computer symbols (I will put a picture of the entire list later). Right now, I am trying to draw a symbol of an analog integrator. Here's what I have right now in code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb, graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsfonts,bm}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ceil{\lceil}{\rceil}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\floor{\lfloor}{\rfloor}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

    \tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, 
    minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em]
    \tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, circle, node distance=1cm]
    \tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
    \tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
    \tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]
    \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            % The block diagram code is probably more verbose than necessary
            \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']
                \node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3, draw, shape border rotate=-90, scale = 2.5, name = integrator]{};
                \draw (integrator.corner 2) -- ++ (-0.5, 0) |- (integrator.corner 3);
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \caption{Control block diagram.}
        \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here's what I have right now:

[image]

Right now, the lines aren't properly connecting to the vertices as I want. Is there a way to properly connect them such that there isn't any space in between the lines and the corners?

Edit: here is a list of analog computer symbols so one can understand what I am trying to do for the integrator (and the derivative):
[image]

Another example (which is seeemingly done on LaTeX):

[image]

Update: here is my example circuit that I want to draw on LaTeX:

[image]

Corresponding equation is here:

[image]

Can someone show me how to generalize the number of inputs to the summer and integrator with detailed explanation on the syntax? I tried to follow the code, but the syntax is super gnarly and very user unfriendly.

Comment: With editing your question you actual ask new question. Please, consider to ask new one as follow-up question to this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all of that can be achieved with `circuitikz`. Here are two examples. BTW, `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[american,siunitx]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
 \draw (0,0) to[amp,t=$\boldsymbol{K}$] ++(3,0); 
 \ctikzset{amplifiers/minus={$k_1$},amplifiers/plus={$k_2$}}
 \draw (0,-1.5) -- ++(1,0) node[op amp, anchor=-](sum){};
 \tikzset{cop amp/.style 2 args={op amp,
 /utils/exec=\ctikzset{amplifiers/minus={},amplifiers/plus={}},
 append after command={%
 pic{rect={#1}{#2}}
 }},
 pics/rect/.style 2 args={code={\let\mytikzlastnode\tikzlastnode
 \draw[thick,fill=white] (\tikzlastnode.bin up|-\tikzlastnode.north) 
 -- ++({-1.1*max(width("#1"),width("#2"))-8pt},0) |- (\tikzlastnode.bin up|-\tikzlastnode.south)
 -- cycle;
 \path (\mytikzlastnode.bin up) node[left=0pt,font=\boldmath] {#1}
  (\mytikzlastnode.bin down) node[left=0pt,font=\boldmath] {#2};
 }}}
 \draw (1,-4)  node[cop amp={$k_1$}{$k_2$}, anchor=-](sum){};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Let me try to explain what

```
\tikzset{cop amp/.style 2 args={op amp,
 /utils/exec=\ctikzset{amplifiers/minus={},amplifiers/plus={}},
 append after command={%
 pic{rect={#1}{#2}}
 }},
 pics/rect/.style 2 args={code={\let\mytikzlastnode\tikzlastnode
 \draw[thick,fill=white] (\tikzlastnode.bin up|-\tikzlastnode.north) 
 -- ++({-1.1*max(width("#1"),width("#2"))-8pt},0) |- (\tikzlastnode.bin up|-\tikzlastnode.south)
 -- cycle;
 \path (\mytikzlastnode.bin up) node[left=0pt,font=\boldmath] {#1}
  (\mytikzlastnode.bin down) node[left=0pt,font=\boldmath] {#2};
 }}}
```

does. It defines a modified `op amp` node. It uses this node, hence the `op amp` key. Then it it removes the `+` and `-` with `/utils/exec=\ctikzset{amplifiers/minus={},amplifiers/plus={}}`. (One may argue that using `/utils/exec` is not always optimal. I agree with Henri on that. However, Ti*k*Z even uses it internally, i.e. it can be found in `tikz.code.tex`. I think here it is fine.) The main ingredient is the `append after command` key, which issues a pic that adds the rectangle. The rectangle gets attached to the node, the name of which is stored in `\tikzlastnode`. Since we are adding other nodes, it gets stored on `\mytikzlastnode`. By measuring the size of the arguments we can make sure that the rectangle is large enough. One could also use `fit` here.

Below is an edit by [Eduardo Alves da Silva](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/202256/eduardo-alves-da-silva), thanks a lot!

**EDIT :** Regarding on how to use, for example, to make the image you've provided:

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{cop amp/.style 2 args={op amp,
    /utils/exec=\ctikzset{amplifiers/minus={},amplifiers/plus={}},
    append after command={%
        pic{rect={#1}{#2}}
}},
pics/rect/.style 2 args={code={\let\mytikzlastnode\tikzlastnode
        \draw[thick,fill=white] (\tikzlastnode.bin up|-\tikzlastnode.north) 
        -- ++({-1.1*max(width("#1"),width("#2"))-8pt},0) |- 
(\tikzlastnode.bin up|-\tikzlastnode.south)
        -- cycle;
        \path (\mytikzlastnode.bin up) node[left=0pt,font=\boldmath] {#1}
        (\mytikzlastnode.bin down) node[left=0pt,font=\boldmath] {#2};
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz} [american voltages]
    \node[draw,minimum size,fill=white] (-1) {-1};
    \draw (-1.east) to[short,-] ++(1,0)
    node[draw, circle,anchor=west] (g) {g};
    \draw (g.east) to[short] ++(0.5,0) node[cop amp={}{}, anchor=-](int1){};
    \draw (int1.out) to[short] ++(1,0) coordinate (aux) to[short] ++(1,0) node[cop amp={}{}, anchor=west] (int2) {};
    \draw (aux) to[short,*-] ++(0,-2) coordinate (aux2);
    \draw[-] (aux2) -- ++(-2,0) node[draw,circle,anchor=east] (dm) {$d/m$};
    \draw[-] (dm) --++(-1.5,0) coordinate (aux2);
    \draw[-] (aux2) |- (int1.+);
    \draw (aux) node[above] () {$-\dot{y}$};
    \draw (int2.out) to[short] ++(0.5,0) node[above] () {$y$};
    \draw (int2.out) to[short, *-] ++(0,-3.5) to[short] ++(-1,0) node[buffer,xscale=-1,anchor=in] (buffer) {};
    \draw (buffer.out) to[short] ++(-0.5,0) node[above] () {$-y$};
    \draw (buffer.out) to[short] ++(-1,0) node[draw,circle,anchor=east] (cm) {$c/m$};
    \draw (cm.west) to[short] ++(-3.5,0) coordinate (aux) to[short] (aux |- int1.west)
    to[short] (int1.west);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, got it, but for the "differential" amplifier below, how do you connect the top and bottom corners of the vertices as shown in my drawing? Here's a link that has another example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_computer#/media/File:Federpendel_als_Analogrechenschaltung.png

Comment: @Superman I am sorry, I cannot follow. Which of your and my symbols are you talking about?

Comment: I am trying to refer to the integrator symbol in my drawing and the "differential amplifier" symbol.

Comment: Hi, Schrodinger's cat, can you explain the code for the third drawing that you did, line by line? I would like to understand the meaning of each line, since the syntax is quite gnarly. Also, how do I vary the number of bins (e.g. 3 instead of 2, as indicated in the spring-mass-damper diagram)?

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for explaining! Btw, in the code that modifies the op amp, is there a way to specify the number of inputs? I know that when defining logic & and or gates, one can specify the number of inputs as parameters. Is there a similar way to somehow parametrize the number of inputs for the modified "op-amp"?

Comment: In the code that modifies the op amp, is there a way to specify the number of inputs? I know that when defining logic & and or gates, one can specify the number of inputs as parameters. Is there a similar way to somehow parametrize the number of inputs for the modified "op-amp"? This question has not been answered. In other words, what if I want 4 inputs? There's gotta be a way to parametrize the inputs.